# Store rows of numbers from a list into arrays without leaving empty cells

Tags: c

I want to read rows of numbers from a file and store each of the rows into separate array to then sort and find the median of each array. The problem I'm having is that each row can have a different amount of numbers in it. I though about using a 2D array that would have enough space to fit the largest row in my file. The problem I see with this is that shorter rows in my file would have empty cells in the array and that could cause errors in the sorting and median.

Is there anyway to store each row of the list without having empty cells in the 2D array?

Here's an example of the number list

1 2 3 4 5
 5 2 8 5 7 4 3
 3 2 5 4 6 5
2 3 1 6 5
9 6 4 6 5 0

Comment: You forgot to post the code that you have wrote so far

Answer (score 0):

Yes you certainly can.

Use dynamic memory allocation for that. This is where it can be useful.

```
int *p[5];

p[0]= malloc( sizeof(int)*10);
if( p[0]== NULL)
{
   fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
   exit(1);
}

p[1]= malloc( sizeof(int)*5);
if( p[1]== NULL)
{
   fprintf(stderr,"Error in malloc");
   exit(1);
}
..
free(p[0]);
free(p[1]);
```

This way now you have created an array of different sizes. Now to remmeber the sizes you can mention another array `sizeArr` which will hold the sizes of different arrays.

What I mean is `sizeArr[0]=10` and `sizeArr[1]=5` denoting the number of elements in `p[0]` and `p[1]`.

Inputting and outputting the elements of `p[0]` and `p[1]` will be similar to that of an array.

```
if (scanf("%d", &p[0][0]) == 1)
    // work with p[0][0];
else
    ...EOF or conversion failure...
```

Looping and printing would be similar to

```
for(size_t arrIndex = 0; arrIndex < 5; arrIndex++)
    for(size_t i = 0; i< sizeArr[arrIndex]; i++ )
       printf("%d", p[arrIndex][i]);
```

Here the benefit will be you will not have to worry about unused memory locations. You will allocate whatever memory you need. Also you can change then as you need using `realloc()` etc.

Note: In this case don't forget to `free` the memory dynamically allocated after you are done working with it.